# A 70s short story about fears made real

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Looking for a short story where two explorers leave a planet but their air has been contaminated by the planet's atmosphere. When in space their minds give form to their childhood fears. They realise that their best defense is hiding under blankets. It was a humourous tale. Read in the 70s, part of an anthology.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is [*Ghost V*](https://classicsofsciencefiction.com/2023/06/20/ghost-v-by-robert-sheckley/) (1954) by Robert Sheckley.

> All clear," he called out to Arnold. "The Grumbler's gone."
> Safe within the ultimate defense against night horrors - wrapped in the
> blankets that had covered their heads - they climbed out of their bunks.
> "l told you the water pistol wouldn't do any good," Gregor said.
> Arnold gave him a sick grin and put the pistol in his pocket. "l'm hanging
> on to it. If I ever get married and have a kid, it's going to be his first present."
> "Not for any of mine," said Gregor. He patted the bunk affectionately.
> "You can't beat blankets over the head for protection.

This story has been [anthologised multiple times](https://isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?45804).

Comment: Great, thanks. Of course, it had to be Sheckley.

Comment: @RoystonNeale - [You're very welcome](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T3iYzyDQ3hQ)